# How can I test that a point is within a given Bézier curve

Tags: opengl, math

I've read from nvidia a way to test whether a given point is within a Bézier curve's 'fill' is by using hardware shaders and using interpolated uv coordinates to test against...

GPU Gems 3, Chapter 25: [Rendering Vector Art on the GPU](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html).

This seems very complicated and I was wondering if there is a simple formula for testing if a point is inside or outside of a Bézier?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if the mouse pointer is inside a path defined by Bezier curves and lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444602/how-can-i-tell-if-the-mouse-pointer-is-inside-a-path-defined-by-bezier-curves-an)

Answer (score 1):

Well, your question is kinda strange.

A curve - let it be a simple line or something more complex like a bezier-curve - is by itself a primitive that has no area. A question asking whether a point is is "inside or outside" of something that has no area is not answerable.

You probably have something else in mind. Please give some hints and maybe add a picture of what you're looking for.